# How do Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE get initialized?

Tags: java, primitive

**This was a stupid question.  I was still learning and was drastically overthinking the situation.**

---

In the source code for `Integer`, it shows `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` declared as:

```
public static final int MIN_VALUE = 0x80000000;  
public static final int MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;
```

My question is, how do these `int`s get declared in the first place?  It seems as though these values would have to be known in order for the values to be validated (or overflow, or whatever) to begin with.  It obviously can't check itself before it's declared, so how does this work?

Comment: isn't because an integer is stored in a 32 bit? therefore those two values are the lower and upper bound in 2's complement

Comment: Your question iis not clear.  The values 0x80000000 and 0x7fffffff are the known values of MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE, by definition.

Comment: I think you have been over thinking the situation.  The max and min values are defined in the JLS and these are the only line needed to set those values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do these ints get declared in the first place?

You are showing the two lines where they are declared...

> it seems as though these values would have to be known in order for the values to be validated

These constants are known and these are their values.

In other words, the limit for an `int` value is constrained by the fact that they have to fit in 32 bits. Those 2 variables are there as a convenience but are not used to determine whether an `int` should overflow or not.

The range of `int` values is defined in the [Java Language Specification #4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) - these constants only reflect the specification:

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - [...]
> - For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive

Comment: I see.  When I saw it, I thought for some reason that they needed to exist in order for them to check themselves, in a weird situation of paradox and circular logic.  This makes much more sense. :)

Answer (score 2):

The validations/possible overflow checks during the compilation stage are done by the compiler, which may have (and probably has) those known values hard coded.

In other words, the compiler doesn't need to look at MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE to validate the program, those values are just treated as any constants and could as far as the compiler is concerned be defined as any value. Of course, if they were changed, your program that actually cares about the constants may not fare as well.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, integers are 32 bits long.  The values `0x07ffffff` and `0x08000000` are the maximum and minimum possible values, by definition.